# What is the characteristics polynomial of some element of the extended field over the base field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I am aware of the characteristics polynomial of a linear operator on a finite dimensional $K$-vector space $V.$ Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space of dimension $n$ and $T:V \longrightarrow V$ be a linear operator on $V.$ Then the characteristics polynomial $\chi_T$ of $T$ is defined as $$\chi_T := \det (XI_n-M)$$ where $M$ is the matrix representation of $T$ w.r.t. some fixed $K$-basis $B$ (say) of $V.$ Clearly $\chi_T \in K[X].$

I am studying Galois theory from NPTEL lecture series. Here I found an assertion made by the instructor which states that " If $L|K$ be a finite Galois extension then for any $y \in L$ the characteristics polynomial $\chi_y$ of $y$ over $K$ is of the form $$\chi_y = \prod_{\sigma \in \text {Gal}\ (L|K)} (X-\sigma (y)).\text{''}$$ But I don't know what's the definition of the charateristics polynomial of some element of the extended field over the base field if the field extension is finite. Is there any linear operator related argument present here too? Because where $L|K$ be a finite field extensioin then we can always think of $L$ as a finite dimensional $K$-vector space. Let $y \in L.$ So there may exist a $K$-linear operator $T$ such that characteristics polynomial $\chi_T$ of $T$ matches with that of the characteristics polynomial $\chi_y$ of $y$ over $K$ and also same thing happens for minimal polynomials. If so then I can relate this two concepts quite easily. Like in linear algebra we know that the minimal polynomial of a linear operator shares same prime factors with the characteristics polynomial. So the concept of characteristics and minimal polynomial in linear algebra matches with the finite field extensions then we can certainly say that the characteristics polynomial of some element is a power of it's minimal polynomial because minimal polynomial of some element of the extended field over the base field is a prime polynomial over the base field for finite field extensions.

Can anybody please give me any sughgestion regarding this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge on this subject is a bit rough, but here's what I think is going on.

Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension and let $\alpha \in L$. Consider the $K$-linear map $m_\alpha\colon L\to L: x\mapsto \alpha x$. The characteristic polynomial of $m_\alpha$ is the defined to be the characteristic polynomial of the element $\alpha\in L$.

In particular, if $\alpha\in K$, then $m_\alpha=cId_L$ and thus the characteristic polynomial is just $(X-\alpha)^n$ where $n=\dim_K(L)$ which is consistent with the formula you give for Galois extensions.

So the only thing going on here to extend the usual definition of characteristic polynomial to an element, is to view said element as an operator acting by multiplication by said element.

Comment: It's indeed a good idea. I appreciate you thought process. But I think that one needs to prove it rigorously without believing it vaguely.

Comment: But $\sigma (\alpha)$ may not be equal to $\alpha$ for all $\sigma \in \text{Gal} (L|K).$ Then how does the formula $(X-\alpha)^n$ you have written for characteistics polynomial is consistent with the formula I mentioned.

Comment: It does for $\alpha\in K$. You can try to prove equality of both formulas as a good exercise on Galois theory. You will need to exploit that the extension is Galois.

Comment: Do you mean this is true for any $\alpha \in L$ if $L|K$ be a finite Galois extension?

Comment: But then $\text{Gal}\ (L|K) = \{\text{id}_L \}.$

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. For any $\sigma\in \text{Gal}(L/K)$ one has that $\sigma$ restricts to the identity on $K$, thus $\sigma(k)=k$ for all $k\in K$.

Comment: That's true since each $\sigma \in \text {Gal}\ (L|K)$ is a $K$-algebra automorphism of $L.$

Comment: But then what will happen? Can you please make it clear to me?

Comment: I think you are totally confused with what I'm saying. I'm not saying that the characteristic polynomial of $\alpha\in L$ is given by $(X-\alpha)^n$. It's given by the characteristic polynomial of the operator $m_\alpha$. If $\alpha\in K$, then both definitions give $(X-\alpha)^n$ as the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99862/discussion-between-math-maniac-and-mathematician-42).

Comment: I don't know the NPTEL course, if they haven't introduced characteristic polynomials of elements in field extensions yet, perhaps the formula you give is simply the definition in that course.

If you wish to show that both definitions coincide for finite Galois extensions, you can, theorems 5.6  and 5.9 in these notes https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf can help you.

Comment: Also, I won't continue in chat, I have to teach a class in -1 minutes :)

Comment: Oh! that's great. Are you a professor?